# JVM process memory usage doesn't match Yourkit profiler

Tags: java, memory-footprint

Any helpful advice will be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

I got a very strict limitation of java memory footprint my java app has to have.

Profiling with Yourkit my java app, which is running with Java 1.8 on MAC using -Xmx40M heap limit, it shows pretty stable memory usage:

- ~40M of non-heap
- ~20M of heap size

The Memory usage per Yourkit displayed below

[image: ~]

The mystery I try to figure out, why the data MAC `top` command shows doesn't match what I see through the Yourkit tool.

[image]

In fact I was expecting to see something like 70M.

I know that JVM process has a certain overhead. Is there any explanation why it needs twice as much as my app takes. Is there a way to figure it out, 
minimize or control it by any means.

Thanks

Comment: The JRE is quite full featured (i.e. large); but more importantly, it manages memory in ways that are not always intuitive. In addition to heap memory, there is also stack memory. And intern pools. It adds up.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, are you aware of any way to get some insight how this extra memory distributed. what JRE features allocate it

Comment: I found very helpful stuff which https://plumbr.io/blog/memory-leaks/why-does-my-java-process-consume-more-memory-than-xmx it has exactly what I needed